# In Apache Server,does making the virtualhost enabled mean the 'Mainhost' is disabled?

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I'm configging my apache server. In httpd.conf, I set the DocumentRoot as below:

```
DocumentRoot "D:/phpwwwroot"
```

And I set the directory node as below:

```
<Directory "D:/phpwwwroot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

For this moment, I haven't enabled the virtual host. And I visit the url: `http://localhost:8080/`, everything is ok.

Next, I tried to set the virtual host.I uncommented out the Virtual hosts. As below:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And my httpd-vhosts.conf is as below:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName www.testphp1.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\VirtualRoot"
    DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html index.htm index.php  
    <Directory "D:\VirtualRoot">  
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride all  
        Order allow,deny  
        Allow from all  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName www.testphp2.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\VirtualRoot1"
    DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html index.htm index.php  
    <Directory "D:\VirtualRoot1">  
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride all  
        Order allow,deny  
        Allow from all  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

And I also edit the hosts file to correct the mapping, you should know what I mean:

```
127.0.0.1 www.testphp1.com
127.0.0.1 www.testphp2.com
```

Next restart apache server, visit below urls:

```
http://www.testphp1.com:8080/
http://www.testphp2.com:8080/
```

Everything is ok. They are mapped to the right folder.

A new question raised, When I try to visit `http://localhost:8080/`, it come to the first virtual host--www.testphp1.com. I means the page shows what `www.testphp1.com` shows.

It seems that the "main host" doesn't work.

How does it happen? How to fix it

Answer (score 0):

It's same situation when you're using IP to access server. It'll show first active website that uses this IP (`localhost` is treated as IP here). You can fix it by defining main website first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add main host also such as:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/phpwwwroot"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So, this means that the Main host in httpd.conf is no more useful,doesn't it? In other words, if we set the virtual host, the main host can be thought as a nonexistent.